# How to take average of every 3 row in a particular column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
   Year  Month ProductCategory  Sales(In ThousandDollars)
0    2009      1   WomenClothing                     1755.0
1    2009      1     MenClothing                      524.0
2    2009      1   OtherClothing                      936.0
3    2009      2   WomenClothing                     1729.0
4    2009      2     MenClothing                      496.0
5    2009      2   OtherClothing                      859.0
6    2009      3   WomenClothing                     2256.0
7    2009      3     MenClothing                      542.0
8    2009      3   OtherClothing                      921.0
9    2009      4   WomenClothing                     2662.0
10   2009      4     MenClothing                      669.0
11   2009      4   OtherClothing                      914.0
12   2009      5   WomenClothing                     2732.0
13   2009      5     MenClothing                      650.0
14   2009      5   OtherClothing                      989.0
15   2009      6   WomenClothing                     2220.0
16   2009      6     MenClothing                      607.0
17   2009      6   OtherClothing                      932.0
18   2009      7   WomenClothing                     2164.0
19   2009      7     MenClothing                      575.0
20   2009      7   OtherClothing                      901.0
21   2009      8   WomenClothing                     2371.0
22   2009      8     MenClothing                      551.0
23   2009      8   OtherClothing                      865.0
24   2009      9   WomenClothing                     2421.0
25   2009      9     MenClothing                      579.0
26   2009      9   OtherClothing                      819.0
27   2009     10   WomenClothing                     2579.0
28   2009     10     MenClothing                      610.0
29   2009     10   OtherClothing                      914.0
```

Every month of a year has 3 different product categories (WomenClothing, MenClothing, OtherClothing), so to represent that we have 3 rows for each month. I want to take average of Sales column for every month, i.e. average of every 3 rows and take that as one value for every month, so that I can reduce the number of rows. 
That is, at the end, I just want to have one row for every month in a year.

Just like this:

```
  Year  Month              Average Sale of each month
0    2009      1                      1071.66
3    2009      2                      1028.0
6    2009      3                      1239.66
10   2009      4                      1415.0
```

Comment: question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Comment: What you are asking is somewhat confusing?  You want every third row? `df[::3]` however you mention average yet, I don't see any averages in your expected output above.  Can you restate or clarify a bit?  Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to groupby month. and use `mean()`.  Or probably groupby both year and month

Comment: @ScottBoston yes i want to take average of every 3 rows in "Sales" column.For your clarification i have edited the output code,please check.

Comment: @user3483203 i guess we need to group by year and month both because months have same values in different years.Basically each month has 3 rows as you can see so i want to covert that into 1 by taking average of every 3 rows of sales column. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['Sales(In ThousandDollars)'].mean().reset_index()

   Year  Month  Sales(In ThousandDollars)
0  2009      1                1071.666667
1  2009      2                1028.000000
2  2009      3                1239.666667
3  2009      4                1415.000000
4  2009      5                1457.000000
5  2009      6                1253.000000
6  2009      7                1213.333333
7  2009      8                1262.333333
8  2009      9                1273.000000
9  2009     10                1367.666667
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the index for your grouping. It would look something like this:

```
df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()
```

If your month column is consistent that you will always have 3 rows for each month in a year, you can groupby year and month to get the same result.

This gives you:

```
        Year    Month   Sales
0   2009    1   1071.666667
1   2009    2   1028.000000
2   2009    3   1239.666667
3   2009    4   1415.000000
4   2009    5   1457.000000
5   2009    6   1253.000000
6   2009    7   1213.333333
7   2009    8   1262.333333
8   2009    9   1273.000000
9   2009    10  1367.666667
```